# Can I export my Azure subscription's entire configuration?

Tags: azure

Is it possible, using the Azure portal or some other means, to export the subscriptions configuration, for example as an XML file?

I mean things like details of web sites / roles, virtual machines, the size of the machines etc?

Then I could export every day and use a diff tool to check nothing has changed by mistake....

Just thought I'd ask before I write a giant PowerShell script.

Comment: Have a look at the Azure Resource Manager. That way you can export to JSON

Comment: Azure Resrouce manager however does not support resources like Cloud Services, API Management, Mobile Services, Azure Scheduler, Azure Automation, Azure Active Directory, Recovery Services, Media Services, etc. ...
And no, there is no such service yet to help you export all your subscriptions configurations.
If you just look for Virtual Machines and Web Sites, Azure Resource Manager may be in help. But if you look for a complete backup - there is no way to easily achieve this today.

Comment: @astaykov - Make that a full answer and I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Resource manager however does not support resources like Cloud Services, API Management, Mobile Services, Azure Scheduler, Azure Automation, Azure Active Directory, Recovery Services, Media Services, etc. ...

So the summary is - No, there is no such service yet to help you export all your subscriptions configurations.

If you just look for Virtual Machines and Web Sites, then Azure Resource Manager may be in help. But if you look for a complete backup - there is no way to easily achieve this today (2015-03-17).

Probably you could write some Powershell script combining the power of Azure Service Management + Azure Resource Manager, but frankly I am not really sure whether that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this would be a nice feature to have. It's often easier to build out the environment via the portal, but copying that from one tenant (dev) to another (prod) would be much faster and easier if it could be exported to JSON or XML and processed via PowerShell.